# Get filename and location from Function

Tags: llvm, clang++, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-3.0

I have an LLVM pass that iterates over LLVM IR code and I would like to get a directory and a filename for both the functions and basic blocks for the original code. I know that when I have an Instruction Pointer, I can easily get the information using the code below: Thanks to @hailinzeng 
([How to get the filename and directory from a LLVM Instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503804/how-to-get-the-filename-and-directory-from-a-llvm-instruction))

```
const llvm::DebugLoc &location = i_iter->getDebugLoc();

if (location && debugLocationInfoOn) {
  std::string dbgInfo;
  llvm::raw_string_ostream rso(dbgInfo);
  location.print(rso);
  std::cout << rso.str();
}
```

However, since the class `Function` and `BasicBlock` do not have a member function `getDebugLoc()`, this doesn't work.  I saw another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166004/llvmdiinstruction-getfilename-returns-filename-with-a-directory-i-just-want-t) using the metadata but I do not know how to get to the `DILocation` or `DIScope` from the metadata. Using

```
MDNode *n = inst->getMetadata("dbg");
DILocation loc(n);   `
```

Gives the error below

> /usr/lib/llvm-3.9/include/llvm/IR/Metadata.def:83:42: note: forward declaration of 'llvm::DILocation'
>   HANDLE_SPECIALIZED_MDNODE_LEAF_UNIQUABLE(DILocation)

I'm using llvm 3.9.

UPDATE ::
Thanks Stanislav Pankevich. I wasn't including the right headers but now I have a new issue. DILocation requires LLVMContext, StorageType, and unsigned Line. How do I get the line number and and storage type from a function pointer?
  `DILocation(LLVMContext &C, StorageType Storage, unsigned Line,`

For those working with a similar issue, you can get LLVMContext using

```
llvm::MDNode * testmd = F.getMetadata("dbg");
F.getContext ()
```

Comment: The `note: forward declaration ...` message indicates you are missing `#include "llvm/IR/DebugInfoMetadata.h"` and maybe `#include "llvm/IR/DebugInfo.h"` imports. See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41715433/598057.

Comment: Are you sure the approach from the linked topic is not working for you: `MDNode *metadata = function->getMetadata(0);`, then `DILocation *debugLocation = dyn_cast<DILocation>(metadata);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the .ll file for your code, you would see that every function has DINode associated with it, something like `!<some_number>`. That's the metadata node number that is has info about that function. The type of that node is [DISubprogram](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1DISubprogram.html) You can access it like this:

```
SmallVector<std::pair<unsigned, MDNode *>, 4> MDs;
F.getAllMetadata(MDs);
for (auto &MD : MDs) {
  if (MDNode *N = MD.second) {
    if (auto *subProgram = dyn_cast<DISubprogram>(N)) {
      errs() << subProgram->getLine();
    }
  }
}
```

You can use all the information that is there in the debug node.

Comment: Great Answer. Had to make a few changes but it worked perfectly

Comment: You can also simply use the method "getSubprogram" on llvm::Function, which directly returns the DISubprogram (if present).

Answer (score 0):

How about if we want column details, which is not possible with DISubprogram.
I tried this:

```
DILocation *debugLocation = dyn_cast<DILocation>(N);
debugLocation->getLine();
```

The sample.ll file does contain these lines:
!10 = !DILocation(line: 1, column: 1, scope: !1)
However, it gives core dumped at run time. Any suggestions please how to get it working.